# Git filtering after renaming the folder

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have this situation.

I was refactoring my repository into two src folders so that I can split the folders with git filter-branch.

so instead of src i created AAA and BBB folders

The problem is that after I follow [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) I get detached git commits with no history.

0
|
0
      <--- break here
0
|
0
|
0
|
0
...

I tried also with this [How to split a git repository and follow directory renames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759345/how-to-split-a-git-repository-and-follow-directory-renames)

By putting BBB and AAA into Name1 and Name2 but it didnt work..

any help on this one, I know it can be done :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the command "git mv" for refactoring existing directories? 
How did you copy the files from one directory to the other?

Comment: In intelliJ. Git should automatically track renaming as far as I know. I think git mv doesnt do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

If i understand you correctly, you have 3 folders in your total git history: *src*, *AAA* and *BBB*.
for basically the hole history, you had only *src*, and in the end you made one commit where you separated files from *src* into *AAA* and *BBB*, thus removing *src*, and creating the two others.

in schematic history view (each line is a commit, latest/newest commit is on top, like in gitk):

```
AAA, BBB
src
src
src
src
.
.
.
```

If you now use `git filter-branch --prune-empty -subdirectory-filter AAA`,
it will remove everything, from every commit in history that is not inside folder *AAA* (and then make *AAA* the new root dir). As folder *AAA* exists only in a single commit in your history, you will be left only with this single commit.

### Solution

There are multiple ways to solve this, but i will explain only what i think is most general and probably most compatible with more complex situations.

How to create the AAA sub-repo by rewriting the whole history

1. locally clone your repo, and work only with the clone
2. Remove the last commit where you manually separated the files into *AAA* and *BBB*.
3. Write a (shell-)script, that removes all files that are should not be part of *AAA*, for example using:

   ```
   git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "${fileName}"
   ```
4. Use this script to rewrite every command in your history, with something like:

   ```
   git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter "myCleanupScript.sh" HEAD
   ```

   (NOTE This last step will likely take a long time!)